# Problem in selecting edge loops

Tags: edit-mode, faces, selection-tools

pressing alt key and then clicking right mouse button keeping cursor on smaller face always select vertical group of faces and keeping cursor on larger faces always select circumferential group of faces. I want to select all smaller faces on circumference. please see images to understand problem. thank you

[image][image]

Comment: Looks like you have double vertices in that mesh, below the 2-nd from the top row faces. I'd suggest running W> Remove Doubles and then checking what is there. Note that selecting any kind of loops depends on the nearest element your cursor is over. Although I'm not really sure which faces are you going to select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem arises because the ratio of the faces you click in combination with the perspective makes you klick the lower or upper part of the smaller faces while klicking the left or rightmost parts of the bigger ones. Try clicking on the edge that leads to the next face in the direction you want your selection to go.